# Popup window using CSS/Javascript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, popup

```
 <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink><asp:MultiView ID="MultiViewSearchState" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="ViewCommands" runat="server">&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Select" OnClick="btn_Click" />&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="ButtonClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="ButtonClear_Click" />
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="ViewSearch" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="ButtonCancel_Click" />
            <dyncontrols:SearchControl runat="server" ID="searchControl"/>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
</ContentTemplate>
```

When pressing the button inside ViewCommands, the View is set to ViewSearch. However, this is done with inline html, and I'd like it to be a popup. **What is the best way to achieve this using only css and/or javascript?**

I've read [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/popups/demo.html) and [this](http://webdesignandsuch.com/how-to-create-a-popup-with-css-and-javascript/) but it wasn't enough for me to understand how to do it in ASP.NET using Views. I have also seen ModalPopupExtenders being used, but those don't work on this page because of some UpdatePanel so I figured I'd do a css/js solution.

Comment: Are you saying you want what is in the ViewSearch to be inside of a popup?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is an example of a popup in jQuery & CSS:
http://www.kompeller.co.uk/6266540/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the CssClass on the elements that you want to style then simply set the styles as the links you provide suggest.  Alternatively if you are using .NET 4 you can set the "ClientID".  The CSS may be something like:

```
.button
{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```